# Delete complete branch from llvm ir

Tags: c++, llvm

There is a branch in ir that I want to delete completely(condtion + branch + true_basic_block + false_basic_block). It looks like this:

```
%4 = icmp sge i32 %2, %3
br i1 %4, label %5, label %7

; <label>:5                                       ; preds = %0
%6 = load i32* %x, align 4
store i32 %6, i32* %z, align 4
br label %9

; <label>:7                                       ; preds = %0
%8 = load i32* %y, align 4
store i32 %8, i32* %z, align 4
br label %9

; <label>:9                                       ; preds = %7, %5
%10 = call dereferenceable(140) %"class.std::basic_ostream"*@_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc(%"class.std::basic_ostream"* dereferenceable(140) @_ZSt4cout, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0))
%11 = load i32* %z, align 4
%12 = call dereferenceable(140) %"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZNSolsEi(%"class.std::basic_ostream"* %10, i32 %11)
%13 = call dereferenceable(140) %"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E(%"class.std::basic_ostream"* %12, %"class.std::basic_ostream"* (%"class.std::basic_ostream"*)* @_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_)
ret i32 0
```

Now to delete it , is there a removeBranch function , or do I need to delete instructions one by one. I have been trying the latter way but I have seen every error from "Basic block in main does not have an terminator" to "use remains when def is destroyed", and many more.. I have used erasefromparent, replaceinstwithvalue, replaceinstwithinst, removefromparent, etc.

Can anyone be kind enough to point me in the correct direction?

This is my function_pass :

```
bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
    for (auto& B : F) 
    for (auto& I : B) 
            if(auto* brn = dyn_cast<BranchInst>(&I))    
                if(brn->isConditional()){
                    Instruction* cond = dyn_cast<Instruction>(brn->getCondition());
                    if(cond->getOpcode() == Instruction::ICmp){
                        branch_vector.push_back(brn);
                        //removeConditionalBranch(dyn_cast<BranchInst>(brn));
                    }
                }

/*For now just delete the branches in the vector.*/
for(auto b : branch_vector)
        removeConditionalBranch(dyn_cast<BranchInst>(b));

return true;
 }
```

This is the output :[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any `RemoveBranch` utility function, but something like this should work. The idea is to delete the branch instruction, then delete anything that becomes dead as a result, and then merge the initial block with the join block.

```
// for DeleteDeadBlock, MergeBlockIntoPredecessor
#include "llvm/Transforms/Utils/BasicBlockUtils.h"
// for RecursivelyDeleteTriviallyDeadInstructions
#include "llvm/Transforms/Utils/Local.h"

void removeConditionalBranch(BranchInst *Branch) {
  assert(Branch &&
         Branch->isConditional() &&
         Branch->getNumSuccessors() == 2);

  BasicBlock *Parent = Branch->getParent();
  BasicBlock *ThenBlock = Branch->getSuccessor(0);
  BasicBlock *ElseBlock = Branch->getSuccessor(1);

  BasicBlock *ThenSuccessor = ThenBlock->getUniqueSuccessor();
  BasicBlock *ElseSuccessor = ElseBlock->getUniqueSuccessor();
  assert(ThenSuccessor && ElseSuccessor && ThenSuccessor == ElseSuccessor);

  Branch->eraseFromParent();
  RecursivelyDeleteTriviallyDeadInstructions(Branch->getCondition());
  DeleteDeadBlock(ThenBlock);
  DeleteDeadBlock(ElseBlock);

  IRBuilder<> Builder(Parent);
  Builder.CreateBr(ThenSuccessor);
  bool Merged = MergeBlockIntoPredecessor(ThenSuccessor);
  assert(Merged);
}
```

This code only handles the simple case you've shown, with the then and else blocks both jumping unconditionally to a common join block (it will fail with an assertion error for anything more complicated). More complicated control flow will be a bit trickier to handle, but you should still be able to use this code as a starting point.

Comment: Should I call removeConditionalBranch while iterating over the instructions or outside of iteration loop(storing it in a vector during iteration) ? I am getting segmentation fault both ways...

Comment: @GauravSharma In general you shouldn't add / remove instructions while iterating over them. I just tested this and I don't get a segfault, so you'll have to give more information.

Comment: @ Ismail Badawi : I have added the pass and its output...please see....

Comment: The above solution works as long as I am not using c++ stuff( iostream, vector, ect) in the input program. For c stuff( tried with printf, etc), it is working. Thanks a lot anyways....